# Separate A dataframe into two -R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that consist of two dataframes(x, y) that I merged unknowingly. How do I seperate them?

When I try to do a split I get Error: cannot allocate vector of size 207.6 Mb

```
z <- split(df, df$y)
```

Comment: How much RAM do you have installed?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I used the index of the columns, I wanted the first 80 Columns. like so:

```
z <- df[,1:80]
```